# Bootstrap nav-tab styling: some CSS rules apply, others don't

Tags: html, css

I need to style the nav-tabs by their `id`. The code for this was working when it had been put in html between bootstrap and css loading, but when moved to base.css only some of this code works (first set of rules).
Please tell me what to do so that all the rules are applied:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />

    <title>Exemplary CSS error</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class ="row" style = "margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="timespan-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#daily">Daily</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#weekly">Weekly</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#monthly">Monthly</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#timespan-menu .nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    background: #CBCBCB;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #343a40;
  }

#timespan-menu .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #212529;
}
#timespan-menu .nav-tabs > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #6c757d;
}
```

Comment: You said here *The code for this was working when it had been put in html between bootstrap and css loading, but when moved to base.css only some of this code works* -- which means that your base.css is being overridden by bootstrap.css -- load bootstrap before your custom styles

Comment: I can't change it. This one is a minimal reproducible version of a bigger project code, @Simp4Code.

Comment: @Swantewit Well what can you change? You must be able to change something otherwise there wouldn't be much point asking the question!

Comment: Yes I can change what you have written below and am doing so right now, @PhilipStratford :) Just shouldn't be meddling with the high-level rules as what is loaded when.

Comment: `#timespan-menu .nav-tabs` is wrong, it's either `#timespan-menu` or ` .nav-tabs` not both as `#timespan-menu` *is* a ` .nav-tabs` not a child of ` .nav-tabs`.

Comment: Well the space was the problem as Philip noticed, @RenevanderLende ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your CSS your second and third rules are being applied to *child elements of the `#timestamp-menu` element which have the class `.nav-tabs`*, whereas in your markup the `#timespan-menu` element has the `.nav-tabs` class itself.

It works if you just remove the spaces between `#timespan-menu` and `.nav-tabs` in your rules, e.g.:

```
#timespan-menu.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #212529;
}
```

You probably want to tidy your CSS up, though. If you're happy that the styling should be applied by ID then you don't really need to further specify the `.nav-tabs` class in your second and third rules.